# creating new variable with ifelse with NA's

Tags: r

I have a data frame that consists of the answers to the question:
"What language do you speak at home?
1=English
2=Spanish
and so on...

```
     first.language second.language third.language fourth.language
1              1              NA             NA              NA
2              1               2             NA              NA
3              1               2             NA              NA
4              2              NA             NA              NA
5              1               2             NA              NA
6              1               5             NA              NA
```

What I want to do is create the variable: "english.home"
"english.home" will be:
1=if English is spoken at home, never mind if it is the first, second... language
2(else)=if English is not spoken at home.

I tried using:

```
student1$english.home = ifelse(student1$first.language==1 |
student1$second.language==1 | student1$third.language==1 |
student1$fourth.language==1,1,2)
```

But i got:

```
>   english.home
1            1
2            1
3            1
4           NA
5            1
6            1
```

Is there any way of accomplishing this without getting an NA on row number four. Because it really doesn’t matter that it is a NA what matters is that it is not English!

I know that the ifelse-Na topic was much debated. I have searched a lot for a solution before posting but could not find it.

Hope someone will help me out of this mess

Comment: for each row ```min(therow,na.rm=T)```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you want.

```
# Read your data
tab <- read.table(text ="  
first.language second.language third.language fourth.language
1              1              NA             NA              NA
2              1               2             NA              NA
3              1               2             NA              NA
4              2              NA             NA              NA
5              1               2             NA              NA
6              1               5             NA              NA")

tab$english.home <- 
  apply(tab, 1, function (x) 2 - any(x == 1, na.rm = TRUE))
print(tab)
#  first.language second.language third.language fourth.language english.home
#1              1              NA             NA              NA            1
#2              1               2             NA              NA            1
#3              1               2             NA              NA            1
#4              2              NA             NA              NA            2
#5              1               2             NA              NA            1
#6              1               5             NA              NA            1
```

We use the fact that `logical` vectors get promoted to `numeric` `0`and `1` when added (or subtracted) with a `numeric`.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps

```
(!rowSums(student1==1 & !is.na(student1))) +1
#1 2 3 4 5 6 
#1 1 1 2 1 1
```