# Constructing a new variable using ifelse with missing data

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to construct a new variable using a ifelse statement that states if you have a MMSE score of <24 or a fast score of >=4 at either w1 or w2 you are classed as 1, if not 0.

The dataframe.

```
   mmse_w1 mmse_w2 fast_w1 fast_w2
1        27      29       1       1
2        28      25       1      13
5        30      22       1       4
7        16       4       4      16
38       25      NA       2      NA
45        0      NA      11      NA
72       NA      NA      10      NA
414      NA      NA      NA      NA

dat$dementia <- with(dat, ifelse(mmse_w1 <24 | fast_w1 >=4 | mmse_w2 <24 | fast_w2 >=4, 1, 0))

    mmse_w1 mmse_w2 fast_w1 fast_w2 dementia
1        27      29       1       1        0
2        28      25       1      13        1
5        30      22       1       4        1
7        16       4       4      16        1
38       25      NA       2      NA       NA
45        0      NA      11      NA        1
72       NA      NA      10      NA        1
414      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
```

However for cases like number 38, where you have data missing at w2 and and the MMSE is >24 or fast is <4, the cases is classed as NA rather than 0.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060063/creating-new-variable-with-ifelse-with-nas), that had a similar problem but I was unable to get that solution working.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What should row 414 be?  NA or zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `TRUE` is 1 and `FALSE` is 0 internally, `pmax` will do it for you:

```
with(dat, pmax(mmse_w1 <24,fast_w1 >=4,mmse_w2 <24,fast_w2 >=4,na.rm=TRUE) )
#[1]  0  1  1  1  0  1  1 NA
```